# Верстка карточек товара, Help

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive

мне нужна помощь с адаптивной версткой карточек. Не могу задать правильное позиционирование блока с `img`. Подскажите, как правильно сделать данную карточку?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой SASS код и HTML код :

```
<div class="item-block mx-auto">
        <div class="item-block-top">
            <a href=""><img src="/public/img/img_product.png" alt="product">
                <span class="badge badge1 badge-danger float-left">New</span>
                <span class="badge badge2 badge-secondary float-right">New</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block-body">
            <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
            <span>Price</span><span class="float-right">OldPrice</span>
            <button>add to card</button><button>view</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Вот SASS

```
    *
    padding: 0
    margin: 0

body
    background-color: #c1c1c1
    .main
        width: 80%
        background-color: #fff
        margin-right: 10%
        margin-left: 10%
        .row
            margin-left: 5%
            margin-right: 5%
            .item-block
                margin-top: 30px
                margin-bottom: 30px
                border: 2px solid lightgrey
                width: 20%
                .item-block-top
                    display: block
                    border: 2px solid lightgrey
                    margin-right: 7.5px
                    margin-left: 7.5px
                    margin-bottom: 20px
                    a
                        display: inline-block
                        position: relative
                        line-height: 0
                        img
                            height: 100%
                            width: 100%
                        .badge1
                            position: absolute
                            left: 0
                            top: 50%
                        .badge2
                            position: absolute
                            right: 0
                            top: 50%
                .item-block-body
                    padding-left: 7.5px
                    padding-right: 7.5px
```

Comment: https://www.sassmeister.com/ есть конвертер для примеров, чтобы можно было сделать пример воспроизводимым

Comment: @kizoso Да это не важно, я могу сюда хоть css поставить, он работать не будет, тут же и bootstrap и img

Comment: сделайте воспроизводимый пример того что у вас уже есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На CSS  :)

```css
.item-block-top {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}

.item-block.mx-auto {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 522px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

body{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="item-block mx-auto">
        <div class="item-block-top">
            <a href=""><img src="https://otvet.imgsmail.ru/download/e647fb84923a6605c02764a3de2e4df6_i-13.jpg" alt="product">
                <span class="badge badge1 badge-danger float-left">New</span>
                <span class="badge badge2 badge-secondary float-right">New</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-block-body">
            <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
            <span>Price</span><span class="float-right">OldPrice</span>
            <button>add to card</button><button>view</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```